# git first number in ls-tree output

Tags: git

Whenever I run `git ls-tree`, the first number in every line is `100644`. What does this number mean, and is it really always that number every time?

The only guess I have is that it's a number for some future compatibility reasons.

--EDIT--

I misread the manual. It turns out that the first number is the `mode`. So I guess my question is what does `mode` mean? (file permissions?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are [Unix filesystem permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Notation_of_traditional_Unix_permissions) in octal notation. The first three digits denote the file type (`100` means directory), and the following three digits represent permissions for the owner, the owning group, and everybody else (respectively).

The following basic permissions can be combined:

- 1 (`--x`): execute
- 2 (`-w-`): write
- 4 (`r--`): read

In other words 644 means "read and write for the owner, read-only for the rest".